# How can I make a function that works on any type from the k8s package?

Tags: go, kubernetes, operator-sdk

Sorry I'm quite a noob at Go so hope this isn't a stupid question. I know pointers in a general sense but struggling with Go semantics.

I can't get this to work:

```
func DeleteOldCronJob(c client.Client, ctx context.Context, namespace string, name string) error {
    cronJob := batchv1beta1.CronJob{}
    key := client.ObjectKey{
        Namespace: namespace,
        Name:      name,
    }
    return DeleteOldAny(c, ctx, name, key, &cronJob)
}

func DeleteOldAny(c client.Client, ctx context.Context, name string, key client.ObjectKey, resource interface{}) error {
    err := c.Get(ctx, key, resource)

    if err == nil {
        err := c.Delete(ctx, resource)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    } else {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

I get an error:

```
interface {} does not implement "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/runtime".Object (missing DeepCopyObject method)
```

The point is so that I can reuse DeleteOldAny on multiple different types, to make my codebase more compact (I could just copy+paste DeleteOldCronjob and change the type).
As far as I read, pointers to interfaces in Go are usually wrong. Also, [the k8s type I'm importing](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/api/batch/v1beta1?utm_source=gopls#CronJob) is just a struct. So, I thought since it's a struct not an interface I should pass resource a a pointer like:

```
        err := c.Get(ctx, key, &resource)
```

But that gives me another error:

```
*interface {} is pointer to interface, not interface
```

So I'm a bit stuck. Am I doomed to copy+paste the same function for each type or is it a simple syntax mistake I'm making?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty much the answer is to use [the unstructured package](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1/unstructured?utm_source=godoc#Unstructured).

I don't think you can do `client.Get()` without a concrete type, which is ridiculous. Go really is a stiff and verbose language, isn't it?

Comment: I think the reason this constraint exists is because of the API being called. There is no API in Kubernetes that lets you list all objects, irrespective of Kind, as far as I know.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

```
func (client.Reader).Get(ctx context.Context, key types.NamespacedName, obj client.Object) error
Get retrieves an obj for the given object key from the Kubernetes Cluster. obj must be a struct pointer so that obj can be updated with the response returned by the Server.
```

so the idea is right to have modular approach and stop reusing the code .

But implementation is wrong , the obj would be the resource you are trying to fetch from cluster which should be passed in the function as a struct pointer.

```
err := c.Get(ctx, key, &resource)
```

here **resource** should be a struct as **Get , delete etc.** expects as pointer to the respective object to be passed .